# node js async registration function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, async-await

Hello guys i need your help with this backend code that controls a registration form.
Heres the problem: i can create an account with the same email of another user even if the catch error is specified. What could be the problem?

some project notes:
framewokrs used :node js, express, mysql2

```
async function registrazione(req, res, next) {
    const db = await makeDb(config); 
    let results = {};
    let results0 = {};
    //correggere inserimento utenti multipli con stessa email
    results0 = await db.query('select * from `utente` where email="?"', [req.body.email])
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
    if (results0.length>0){
          res.send("user already registered");}

    else{
// inserimento utente
    try {
        await withTransaction(db, async() => { 

            // generazione della password cifrata con SHA512
            results = await db.query('SELECT sha2(?,512) AS encpwd', [req.body.pass]) //prende la password e applica la codifica sha2
                .catch(err => {
                    throw err;
                });

            let encpwd = results[0].encpwd;
            console.log('Password cifrata');
            console.log(results);
            results = await db.query('INSERT INTO `utente` (nome, cognome, email, password) \
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
        [

                    req.body.firstname,
                    req.body.name,
                    req.body.email,
                    encpwd
                ])
                .catch(err => {
                    throw err;
                });
            console.log(`Utente ${req.body.email} inserito!`);
            res.render('landing', { title: 'Registrazione effettuata', utente_loggato: req.session.utente});
        });
    } catch (err) {
        var message =  'Indirizzo e-mail già in uso, torna alla home e registrati nuovamente';
        next(createError(message));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that `await withTransaction(db, async () => { ... })` is going to work.  When you pass an asynchronous callback, an API rarely also returns a promise.  So, using `await` on something that doesn't return a promise does nothing useful.

Comment: Hello friend, my general recommendation is to get familiar with callback hell and promises.